# XML file saved from Swing application

Tags: java, xml, swing

I'm developing a Java Swing Application, and I want to create objects and save them in a XML file, with the information that a user writes in some text fields.

How can I save that data into a XML file, to form those objects?

Comment: Look at `XMLEncoder`/`XMLDecoder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own XML-Writer to write out objects/text to a XML file. For example using DOM

```
public boolean writeCommonSettingsFromGUI()
  {
      DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

      Element rootElement = doc.createElement("NAME_OF_A_ELEMENT");
      doc.appendChild(rootElement);

      Element xmlInfo = doc.createElement("NAME_OF_ANOTHER_ELEMENT");
      xmlInfo.setTextContent("YOUR_CONTENT_TO_SET_FOR_THIS_ELEMENT");
      rootElement.appendChild(xmlInfo);

      TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputPropertiesFactory.S_KEY_INDENT_AMOUNT, "5");
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

      StreamResult result = null;

      result = new StreamResult(new File("FILE_PATH_WHERE_TO_SAVE_YOUR_XML"));

      transformer.transform(source, result);

      return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use castor framework, you can map your java class to xml file and vice versa